# Submitting binary for Appstore review with Appstore provisioning and AdHoc Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval, ad-hoc-distribution

I have submitted approx 20+ Application on App Store with Ad-Hoc provisioning profile and all have been approved and working perfectly.

I just want to make sure that If we submit binary with Ad-Hoc Provisioning this will create any problem.

What is the best way to submit build on Appstore with the Ad-Hoc provisioning or Appstore provisioning and why?

If we go to developer account then Here are 2 options to create provisioning profile for distribution build.

**App Store-**
  Create a distribution provisioning profile to submit your app to the App Store.

**Ad Hoc-**
Create a distribution provisioning profile to install your app on a limited number of registered devices.

Please share your thoughts So next time I will keep it in mind and will use best way to upload build.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, the XCode will automatically choose the "App Store" provisioning profile when you submitting the app. Even if you set "Ad Hoc" profile for code sign in Build Settings. Are you sure the Ad Hoc have been applied for submitted apps?

Comment: No, At the time of upload I always choose submit for Appstore with the adhoc provisioning

Comment: @ArvindKumarMobulous You must take the App Store profile; and you did if your apps are accepted and actually work. Describe your submission process. How do you build and submit and on which point do you choose "Ad Hoc"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting your application for the beta testing through the test flight than you can use Appstore or Ad Hoc provisioning profile.

But in case when you are uploading for publishing the application you must use the App Store provisioning profile only. This is more preferred. There is no meaning for using the Ad Hoc provisioning profile which has limited devices added & has limited access.

Hope this helps to everyone.